# I am getting the error: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$profile has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a relationship between two models in my application: Users and Profile. The User model has a `hasOne` relationship with the profile model. When I try to run an update method from my Profile Controller I get the error: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$profile has no effect.
This is my update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'facebook' => 'required|url',
        'youtube' => 'required|url'
    ]);
    $user = Auth::user();
    //dd($user);
    if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
    {
        $avatar = $request->avatar;
        $avatar_new_name = time() . $avatar->getClientOriginalName();
        $avatar->move('uploads/avatars', $avatar_new_name);
        $user->profile->avatar = 'uploads/avatars/' . $avatar_new_name ; 
        $user->profile->save();
    }
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->profile->facebook = $request->facebook;
    $user->profile->youtube = $request->youtube;
    $user->profile->about = $request->about;
    $user->save();
    $user->profile->save();
    if($request->has('password'))
    {
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user->save();
    }
    Session::flash('success', 'Account profile updated.');
    return back();

}
```

This is my User.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}

public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
}
```

This is my Profile.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'avatar', 'youtube', 'facebook', 'about'
];
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Profile instance, save it to the database and then call the following method to setup the relationship. At present you are trying to assign properties to something which doesn't exist.

Do the following

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->myvar = 'value';

$profile->save();
```

Then associate (one of these will work but I haven't tested the code)

```
$user->profile()->save($profile);
$user->profile()->associate($profile);
```

Comment: The data already exists in the database. I am only trying to edit

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a relational object of `$user`. You may try with this.

```
$user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('profile')->first();
```

Instead of `$user = Auth::user();`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion but I am still getting the error

Comment: You have to create both of `$user` and `$profile` instance and then save individually.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your update function with this and try again

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'facebook' => 'required|url',
        'youtube' => 'required|url'
    ]);

    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    if($user) {
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        if($request->has('password'))
        {
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        }
    }

    if( $user->save() ) {

        $profile = Profile::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

        $profile->facebook = $request->facebook;
        $profile->youtube = $request->youtube;
        $profile->about = $request->about;

        if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
        {
            $avatar = $request->avatar;
            $avatar_new_name = time() . $avatar->getClientOriginalName();
            $avatar->move('uploads/avatars', $avatar_new_name);
            $profile->avatar = 'uploads/avatars/' . $avatar_new_name ;
        }
    }

    if($profile->save()) {
        Session::flash('success', 'Account profile updated.');
    } else {
        Session::flash('error', 'Failed to update.');
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting the error: ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Creating default object from empty value

Comment: What's happened to the `users` table? The `profile` table may null according to the user. please check.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. The login User did not have a corresponding Profile in the database. So when there is an attempt to update the Profile the system cannot find the corresponding record